# Are strong Chess AI's local on mobile devices?

Tags: game-ai, chess

Just wondering about the architecture of strong Chess AI in a mobile, because networking is generally assumed by mobile developers, but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In fact, I'm the developer of some mobile chess apps. [Disclaimer]

I would argue my chess engine products for the iOS (http://www.smallchess.com) are powerful and strong enough to beat any chess grandmaster. My apps run without network connection,

Comment: Thanks for that!  (I'm looking forward to trying your app, which looks very high quality.